# Auto size TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following `ListView`:

```
<ListView Name="listView1" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <StackPanel>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}"  />
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Link}" FontSize="18" />
              </StackPanel>
           </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

My problem is with the `TextBlock` cantaining the `Content`. If the text exceeds the width of the screen I want the remaining text to appear on the second row of the `TextBlock`.

Is this possible with a `TextBlock` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the TextWrapping property, like so:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
```

Comment: Oh courses, and I already try that, but instead of Content I was setting it for the Title. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use `TextWrapping` property

```
<ListView Name="listView1" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="30" Foreground="#24FF2E" />
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Content}" FontSize="18" Foreground="#D1D8E8" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Link}" FontSize="18"  Foreground="#009FFF"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```